# How to clip off a part of an overlaping image in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Hello I would like to know how I can clip off part of a texture that overlaps with another texture. Like the image below but without rendering part of the overlapped white "X". The octagon has an alpha transparency, i want to be able to see every thing under it except part of the overlapped white X.

[image: white sprite should be clipped]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you
[libgdx open gles 2.0 stencil alpha masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820240/libgdx-open-gles-2-0-stencil-alpha-masking)

It Looks like you Need to use a mask..

Another link, where I had my own Problem, where I used a depth buffer would be this here:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/119821/libgdx-shaperender-within-a-circle-as-limitter/119869#119869

I hope this will help you furthermore.